# Tortoise SVN Merging 2 Branches (Grab all revisions)

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoise SVN client for windows to communicate with my repository. This is what I am confused with regards to merging. When merging to the latest revision, are all previous revisions carried over with the merging?

This is the step I made through merging.

1. On tortoise svn menu, I selected "Merge".
2. Selected the "Merge a range of revisions" as the merge type. Click Next.
3. On the Revision range to merge box, I clicked the "Show Log" button and the list of revisions appeared.
4. From the popup window containing the list of revisions, I selected / checked the most latest revision. Click Ok

Is it the proper way to merge two branches using tortoise svn client?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - **NO**

- When you merge, you merge **trees history**, not revisions per se
- When you have explicitly selected only *some revisions* (latest in "merge from" is edge case of selecting range) only selected revisions changes are merged
- With SVN-client, which have merge-tracking (1.5+) you can don't worry about selecting source-range (except cases, when you know, that you do) and leave range empty - all revisions from source branch (which wasn't merged earlier) will be merged to target

Good (correct) workflow in assumption, that you want to merge all unique changes from A to B

1. Have clean Working Copy of B (no mixed revisions, no local modification)
2. Select Merge  Merge a range
3. URL to merge from - A-URL
4. Revision range - leave empty